# Maven set up questions

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I just started using researching Maven and am trying to figure it all out. I had to use it with this online tutorial in mongoDB i'm taking to run maven on a couple of different pom.xml files to build a couple of different apps. I have a few questions about Maven though that will hopefully help me better understand how to use it.

I understand the concept of Mavens pom.xml including different dependancies. When i ran Maven on a certain pom.xml in eclipse, the file loaded everything necessary for Spark and FreeMarker. How is this different from a regular import statement? couldn't your source code import FreeMarker/Spark? or is this some kind of difference between frameworks and classes?

Also it seems the only way to make an existing project into a maven project with a proper pom would be to create new maven project (with the same project name?)and copy all of your source code into the src folder. Would you then have to build up test code for all of your source code? how important is the test code in a maven project?

So, a new maven project from scratch would build the proper maven 2 directory structure after i identify artifactID, groupID, and version, then I would build all my code under the src folder, tests under the test folder and manually add dependancies to the pom as i go?

I just want to get my head around what makes Maven so important so I can fully utilize using it. Any kind of information is greatly appreciated.
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all let me just say that you have too many questions in your post. Seem like you should pick up a book on maven or go through some good tutorials to get a firm grasp on how it works.

> "How is this different from a regular import statement? couldn't your source code import FreeMarker/Spark?"

You couldn't use an import statement if you didn't have the jar dependency (for any non standard java class. Maven downloads the jars into a local repository so that you can use them for this project and any future projects. Just like if you aren't using maven, you still need to add the library to your project to use it.

> "Also it seems the only way to make an existing project into a maven project with a proper pom would be to create new maven project.."

A lot of times in Eclipse, all you need to do is right click on your project and in the context menu go to configure->convert to maven project.

> "then I would build all my code under the src folder, tests under the test folder and manually add dependancies to the pom as i go?"

Sources go in src/main/java, test sources files (normally test cases) go in test/main/java... yes add dependencies as you go. Most IDEs will have user interfaces you can easily search for dependencies. Like Eclipse, you can click add from the dependencies tab from your pom view or right click your project->maven->add dependency. You can just type in some key search key words to find what you're looking for. (You need to remember to index your local repo so that eclipse can find every dependency out there on the central market)

> "I just want to get my head around what makes Maven so important so I can fully utilize using it."

Main things I find useful:

- Dependency management, especially with transitive dependencies. For example jar A depends on jar B and jar B depends on jar C and jar C depends on jar D. That would be a headache trying to take care of and remember all those things, especially the larger your project and dependency tree gets. If you go to your pom, and go to the dependency hierarchy tab (and you have a few dependencies) you may notice this
- Plugins. This is one of the main features of Maven. You should really learn how they work. There is a vast array of plugins out there that will make the build process easier and customizable for different scenarios. You can even extend maven by [creating your own plugins](http://maven.apache.org/plugin-developers/). There are [built in plugins](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/) that are already useful. But there also many third party ones you'll find out there for your specific needs.
- The [build lifecycle](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html) that you can hook into.